# Refrescar una pantalla al cerrar sweetalert

Tags: ajax, modal, sweetalert2

tengo un sweetalert que se muestra despues de una accion dentro de un modal que tiene una peticion en ajax para guardar ciertos datos del modal,  una vez que procesa la informacion, avisa mediante el sweetalert que la operacion se ha ejecutado con exito,  y al momento de dar clic en OK para que cierre la notificacion, logre que me cierre la ventana que origina el modal, pero al regresar a la ventana original no me la refresca.

```js
success: function (msg) {
  alert(msg);
  $("#modalCapturaTerminalBancaria").modal('hide');
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Operacion realizada con exito',
    text: 'Haga click en OK para salir',
    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR'
  }) // final del swal //
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        window.close();
        window.opener.location.reload();
        //window.history.back();         
      }
    });
},
```

eh estado probando con una serie de instrucciones que en diferentes foros comentan pueden ser de utilidad, pero hasta el momento ninguno me refresca la vista original y si es importante que refresque esta vista para evitar que el usuario quiera efectuar de nuevo la misma operación.

Comentario adicional:  la ventana que se habre y lanza el modal se hace su peticion utilizando `target='_blank'`  una vez que habre esta ventana, se despliega el modal. Eliminando este `target='_blank'` , y haciendo pruebas me regresa hasta otra ventana previa y si la refresca.

Saludos
Gracias

Comment: prueba con `window.location.reload();`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Ya lo he utilizado sin exito. lo mas que he logrado que haga es que cierre la ventana donde se dispara el modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el `location.reload()` en el `then()`

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo...

```
swal({
  title: "Confirmar acción",
  text: "¿Estás seguro de que deseas continuar?",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    // aquí se ejecuta el código si el usuario hace clic en el botón "Aceptar"
    location.reload(); // refresca la página actual
  } else {
    
  }
});
```

Comment: agradezco tu aporte, sin embargo cualquiera de las peticiones que haga en sus diversas formas ninguna logra que se refresque la pantalla de origen.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la propieda `isConfirmed` de sweetAlert y después has el `window.location.reload();`

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
  showDenyButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Save',
  denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
}).then((result) => {
  /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    window.location.reload();
    /*aca notarás que se repite la alerta, eso es por el reload();*/
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
    /*tu resultado si es negado*/
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: lo que sucedio fue que me regresa el modal nuevamente.

Comment: @Cesarin En el ejemplo que pongo es correcto, como lo explicó en el código, siempre ejecuta el alert porque es un ´reload()´ y no hay más lógica; en tu caso debería hacer el reload de tu pagina, o en su defecto puedes agregar más lógica ahi.

Comment: Me refiero a que me regresa un modal donde previamente capture datos y después de haber hecho  clik en el botón "guardar" ,  se despliega el sweetalert una vez que ya proceso los datos notificando que se guardaron exitosamente, a partir de ahí es el código que expuse.  Y asi como lo expones me regresa el modal.